Failed to Build the Cardano Node
got an error while updating the cabal for node. I am following the cardano documentation.
https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardano-node/installing-cardano-node/#building-and-installing-the-node
 cabal update
Cloning into '/home/konma/src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/src/threepenn_-23436291897ec03d'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 5094, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (308/308), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (180/180), done.
remote: Total 5094 (delta 126), reused 264 (delta 114), pack-reused 4786 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (5094/5094), 4.31 MiB | 10.97 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2806/2806), done.
HEAD is now at e3bb828 Allow hashable 1.4 (#260)
Cloning into '/home/konma/src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/src/Win32-net_-e9415802910225c6'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1797, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (297/297), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (152/152), done.
remote: Total 1797 (delta 161), reused 238 (delta 124), pack-reused 1500 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (1797/1797), 1.77 MiB | 10.21 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (923/923), done.
HEAD is now at 3825d3a Merge pull request #9 from input-output-hk/coot/createNamedPipe-error
Cloning into '/home/konma/src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/src/cardano-b_-c0de99f0ccd585cd'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 12172, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3486/3486), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1174/1174), done.
remote: Total 12172 (delta 2517), reused 2909 (delta 2145), pack-reused 8686 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (12172/12172), 11.39 MiB | 10.94 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (6928/6928), done.
HEAD is now at 41545ba Merge pull request #243 from input-output-hk/lehins/expose-packed
Cloning into '/home/konma/src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/src/cardano-c_-e62f2aeae532ef4f'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1542, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (124/124), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (70/70), done.
remote: Total 1542 (delta 42), reused 99 (delta 35), pack-reused 1418 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (1542/1542), 504.22 KiB | 4.71 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (641/641), done.
HEAD is now at f730793 Merge pull request #69 from newhoggy/add-ghc-8.6.5-and-8.10.2-to-ci
Cloning into '/home/konma/src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/src/cardano-l_-793ecdcee1fc1ce7'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 176008, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (8817/8817), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4198/4198), done.
remote: Total 176008 (delta 5178), reused 6063 (delta 3210), pack-reused 167191 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (176008/176008), 113.70 MiB | 9.29 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (98936/98936), done.
HEAD is now at 3df3ca8db Merge pull request #2651 from input-output-hk/jc/update_plutus
Cloning into '/home/konma/src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/src/cardano-p_-98329c466570048a'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2161, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (443/443), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (190/190), done.
remote: Total 2161 (delta 251), reused 386 (delta 226), pack-reused 1718 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (2161/2161), 573.45 KiB | 5.57 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (985/985), done.
HEAD is now at bb4ed71 Merge pull request #158 from input-output-hk/nc/drop-strict
Cloning into '/home/konma/src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/src/ekg-forwa_-e7958ca478e40f05'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 831, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (181/181), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (84/84), done.
remote: Total 831 (delta 95), reused 148 (delta 79), pack-reused 650 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (831/831), 216.22 KiB | 9.83 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (417/417), done.
HEAD is now at 297cd9d unversionedProtocolCodec simplified.
Cloning into '/home/konma/src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/src/flat-3f12f6162a356f6a'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4125, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (344/344), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (71/71), done.
remote: Total 4125 (delta 300), reused 274 (delta 273), pack-reused 3781 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (4125/4125), 1.16 MiB | 10.73 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2746/2746), done.
HEAD is now at ee59880 Don't use the unsafe decodeUtf8
Cloning into '/home/konma/src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/src/goblins-7fe4f5e9bbbd1224'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 462, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (39/39), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Total 462 (delta 15), reused 29 (delta 11), pack-reused 423 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (462/462), 135.49 KiB | 9.68 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (185/185), done.
HEAD is now at cde90a2 Re-enable support for GHC 8.6.5
Cloning into '/home/konma/src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/src/hedgehog-_-d2bdd077e79afffb'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 5835, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5736/5736), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (567/567), done.
remote: Total 5835 (delta 5116), reused 5607 (delta 5060), pack-reused 99 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (5835/5835), 3.88 MiB | 6.13 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5160/5160), done.
HEAD is now at edf6945 Module re-exports (#5)
Cloning into '/home/konma/src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/src/iohk-moni_-c7ca6b005d6f76c5'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 10406, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (745/745), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (273/273), done.
remote: Total 10406 (delta 376), reused 668 (delta 336), pack-reused 9661 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (10406/10406), 35.17 MiB | 11.00 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5885/5885), done.
HEAD is now at 808724f Merge #620
Cloning into '/home/konma/src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/src/optparse-_-5b3aca9bcb30ab3a'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 5003, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (803/803), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (90/90), done.
remote: Total 5003 (delta 757), reused 713 (delta 713), pack-reused 4200 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (5003/5003), 1.16 MiB | 10.55 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2858/2858), done.
HEAD is now at 7497a29 Rename forked package
Cloning into '/home/konma/src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/src/ouroboros_-268d3b2310e5b441'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 161051, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (7249/7249), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2071/2071), done.
remote: Total 161051 (delta 4318), reused 6542 (delta 3794), pack-reused 153802 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (161051/161051), 43.04 MiB | 11.02 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (94924/94924), done.
HEAD is now at 48e498cfe Merge #3599
Cloning into '/home/konma/src/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/src/plutus-3b55de0732f6b166'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 169887, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4980/4980), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (959/959), done.
remote: Total 169887 (delta 4453), reused 4370 (delta 3942), pack-reused 164907 (from 1)
Receiving objects: 100% (169887/169887), 247.16 MiB | 10.51 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (106629/106629), done.
fatal: Could not parse object 'fc5fe94d3d9525d032bcbc79ff0e1ebcfd8ef143'.


What are you trying to build, the master branch? A release tag? Something else?

git fetch --all --recurse-submodules --tags _____
git tag | sort -V _____
git checkout tags/workbench-genesis-0
________ and in this I am doing cabal update for cardano repo

Why are you checking out a workbench tag?

I thought it was the latest. | now I am doing 9.2.1 and it is working fine

That's referencing an unreleased version of plutus. Why are you building that particular branch?

furthermore it's a 2 year old branch.

yes I realized that I changed it to 9.2.1
i was able to update and build but I am unable to run node from anywhere but cardano-node directory.
~/.local/bin have both cardano-node as well as cardano-cli

error I am getting when I run from different directory
`InvalidYaml (Just (YamlException "Yaml file not found: ./mainnet/config/config.json"))
cardano-node: YAML exception:
Yaml file not found: ./mainnet/config/config.json`

You probably need to specify the full path to the config file in your parameters.

Yes it worked.
added complete path
